# JOIN четырёх таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

[image: БД]

```
SELECT 
    divisions.`name` AS 'Подразделение',
    `staff units`.`name` AS 'Штатная единица',
    `staff units`.salary AS 'Оклад',
    `unit type`.`percentage of allowances` AS 'Процент надбавки за вредные условия труда',
    `staff units`.`percentage of allowances` AS 'Процент надбавки за ненормированный рабочий день',
    (`staff units`.salary * (1 + `unit type`.`percentage of allowances` + `staff units`.`percentage of allowances`)) AS 'Зарплата'
FROM
    `distribution of staff members`
        JOIN
    divisions ON `distribution of staff members`.iddivision = divisions.id
        JOIN
    `staff units` ON `distribution of staff members`.idstaffunit = `staff units`.id
ORDER BY 
    divisions.`name`;
```

Есть идеи, как дописать к FROM объединение между `distribution of staff members` и `unit type`, где `unit type`.id является внешним ключем таблицы divisions.idunit. HELP!

Comment: А в чем сложности то. тут аж два примера как делается join. еще один дописывается по аналогии.

Comment: Да, вот только это будет отношение между `distribution of staff members` и `unit type` - но `distribution of staff members` не имеет ключа `unit type`

Comment: И что из того. Вы в фразе ON можете использовать любые таблицы, которые были описаны до текущей фразы JOIN

Comment: Знаю, и опять же, нету связи между `distribution of staff members` и `unit type`

Comment: Как нет, вы же сами написали что она есть с таблицей divisions, которая в запросе уже есть. `join unit type ON unit type.id=divisions.idunit`

Comment: Затупил. извиняюсь.

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставьте схему данных текстом, а не картинкой.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    divisions.`name` AS 'Подразделение',
    `staff units`.`name` AS 'Штатная единица',
    `staff units`.salary AS 'Оклад',
    `unit type`.`percentage of allowances` AS 'Процент надбавки за вредные условия труда',
    `staff units`.`percentage of allowances` AS 'Процент надбавки за ненормированный рабочий день',
    (`staff units`.salary * (1 + `unit type`.`percentage of allowances` + `staff units`.`percentage of allowances`)) AS 'Зарплата'
FROM
    `distribution of staff members`
        JOIN
    `staff units` ON `distribution of staff members`.idstaffunit = `staff units`.id
        JOIN
    divisions ON `distribution of staff members`.iddivision = divisions.id
        JOIN
    `unit type` ON divisions.idunit = `unit type`.id
ORDER BY divisions.`name`;
```